# Prometheus/Grafana Rate()....what Unit for Y Axis

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a counter that I am plotting on Grafana.

```
rate(processed_work_items_total{job="MainWorker"}[1m])
```

I am not getting the expected numbers in Grafana.

What I want is the # of Work Items Processed per minute.

Is my query wrong? or my Unit of Measure in my Y Axis. I currently have it as ops/min and its giving me a super small number.

Comment: After a bit of google...maybe my query should be sum(increase(processed_work_items_total[1m]))? Is that correct? If so then what is the Unit of measure for my Y Axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate),  `rate(processed_work_items_total{job="MainWorker"}[1m])` will calculate the number of work items processed *per second*, measured over the last one minute (that's the `[1m]` from your query).

If you want the number of items per minute, simply multiply the above metric with 60.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. Should I decrease the [1m] to something like [15s], then multiply that by 4, to get a more granular graph?

Comment: No, the [1m] refers to over what time frame the rate is measured but the rate itself is always in items per second. You could use irate (see the docs for an explanation of rate vs irate) if you have very spiky data but generally you should still multiply by 60 if you want item per minute.

Comment: `increase(foo[1m])` will do the same as `rate(foo[1m]) * 60` (with some magic thrown in). Do note, however, that computing a rate over 1 minute every minute will throw away one data point every minute, so you should at the very least use a step that's lower than 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate per-minute increase rate for a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) metric, then use `increase(...[1m])`. For example, the following query returns the increase of `processed_work_items_total{job="MainWorker"}` time series over the last minute:

```
increase(processed_work_items_total{job="MainWorker"}[1m])
```

Note that the `increase()` function in Prometheus may return unexpected results due to the following issues:

- It may return fractional results over integer metric because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details.
- It may miss counter increase between the last raw sample just before the lookbehind window specified in square brackets and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window.
- It may miss the initial counter increase at the beginning of the time series.

These issues are going to be addressed in Prometheus according to [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit). In the mean time it is possible to use [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html), which is free from these issues.